# How to block Google service workers?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

After last Chrome update Youtube starts random "service workers" that take 100% CPU usage. They appear in the Task Manager. They don't even close when you close the tab, you have to end the process manually. How can I block their "service workers"?

OS is MacOS Catalina

Comment: A website cannot start a service on your computer.

Comment: he could be talking about the chrome task manager, by clicking shift-esc while in chrome

Comment: I'm guessing this is a reference to HTML5 web workers: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webworkers.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension in chrome that can block service workers per domain, and remember that setting.

It is called "Block Service Workers" Chrome extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-service-workers/ceokjgeibfjfcboemhdpkdalankbmnej?hl=en